# Passing a reference to $scope object through Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got an item in controller $scope. It's taken from API and passed to a factory to format it in a way that would make it easy to display.

```
angular.module('app').controller 'CustomersCtrl', ['$scope', 'CustomerDetailsFactory', function($scope, CustomerDetailsFactory) {
  $scope.item = { 
    full_name: "Jane Doe"

    //more values here 
  };

  $scope.details = CustomerDetailsFactory.get($scope.item);

}]

angular.module('app').factory 'CustomerDetailsFactory', [function() {
  var get = function(item) {
    var detailed = [{
      label: "Full name"
      value: item.full_name
    }

    //more objects here
    ];
   return detailed;
  }
  return {get: get};
}]
```

Then details are displayed via ng-repeat. They need to be editable so user can edit some fields and save them. I display them like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in details">
  <label> {{detail.label}} </label>
  <p ng-if="!editMode"> {{ detail.value }} </p>
  <input ng-if="editMode" ng-model="detail.value"></input>

  //more fields like this

</div>
```

Let's say `$scope.editMode` is changed to true, an input is displayed and changed.

The problem is, changed value is saved in `$scope.details` model but not in `$scope.item` model (which was passed to factory, I believe by reference). And I need to send to the server a JSON with an object just like one I got before, not with a structure completely changed by the factory, which was needed only for nice display.

Please explain how can I make the `$scope.details` object "binded" by reference to `$scope.item` object so when I change details also original item changes.

Comment: FYI - You are mixing up with `CustomerDetailsFactory` and `DetailsFactory` ?

Comment: No, I just didn't clean up code enough for the example, I'll fix it : ) There can be some syntax errors because I write in CoffeScript and Jade but don't bother pointing on them, I am sure that everything works properly in terms of syntax.

Comment: Well, your idea looks like a bad idea to me. Labels to display in the view don't belong to a service, and you should simply write your template using the real object directly, rather that iterating on fields. This strategy won't work very long anyway: you will want to display some fields in a different way, with a different style, on several columns, etc.

Comment: It works because I have multiple views that use the same scheme to display items. I get what you're saying, I just thought I can make the view more reusable (now I have the same view for multiple different lists).

Comment: When you wrote `item.full_name`, you passed value and not reference. Here is a sample demo, maybe that can help - http://plnkr.co/edit/hwkS6jcFTvyPVGuKJtDy?p=preview

Comment: @nikhil yeah but this just makes ng-repeat useless.

Comment: Eh I still need to create a different factory for every view : (. I think you're right @JBNizet and I'll probably need to refactor. But anyway, is there any way to make this thing work? Just curious here.

Comment: I refactored like @JBNizet suggested, using the real object in view, and it works like a charm now. Still curious if there is a solution.